# Eclipse/Ant build failure - com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on the classpath

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I get the following error when I try to build my project in eclipse using Ant.
Searching for solutions suggests that JAVA_HOME should point to JDK instead of JRE and there should be a tool.jar in JAVA_HOME/lib folder. As shown in the following error message, JAVA_HOME is pointing to the JDK, but it doesn't have tools.jar in the lib folder. Is it correct to assume Oracle is no longer shipping tools.jar with the JDK? Where can I find com.sun.tools.javac.Main ?

```
com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on the classpath.
Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK.
It is currently set to "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73"
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it correct to assume Oracle is no longer shipping tools.jar with the JDK?

No, tools.jar should be present in the latest JDK8 installation. It seems your JDK installation is incomplete. Try re-doing a fresh install.

Comment: You are right. My java installation was corrupted it seems. I ran the installer few time earlier without uninstalling the existing ones. This time I first uninstalled the existing jdk via Add/Remove Programs and ran the installer and it fixed my problem. Thanks.